# Applying .mean() to a grouped data with a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` that looks like this:

```
Day         Country         Type        Product         Cost        

Mon         US              1           a1              0
Mon         US              2           a1              5
Mon         US              3           a1              6
Mon         CA              1           a1              8
Mon         CA              2           a1              0
Mon         CA              3           a1              1
```

I am trying to make it to this:

```
Day         Country         Type        Product         Cost        Average

Mon         US              1           a1              0           (5+6)/2
Mon         US              2           a1              5           (5+6)/2
Mon         US              3           a1              6           (5+6)/2
Mon         CA              1           a1              8           (8+1)/2
Mon         CA              2           a1              0           (8+1)/2
Mon         CA              3           a1              1           (8+1)/2
```

The idea is to group it by `Country` and `Product` and get the average cost but take the `Costs` where its `>0`.

What I've tried:

```
np.where(df['Cost']>0, df.loc[df.groupby(['Country','Product'])]['Cost'].mean())
```

But I get:

> ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key

What is the best practice solution of applying built-in functions like `.mean(), max(), etc` to a grouped pandas dataframe with a filter?

Comment: Do you want to ignore rows where cost is equal to zero?

Comment: Yes, in a scenario when I only group by `Country` and `Product` I ignore the lines where the `Cost` is  0. If I would add `Type` to the `groupby` then I would add `0` in those lines where `Cost` is `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First idea is replace `0` to `NaN`s and then use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `mean`, missing values are omitted by default:

```
print (df.assign(new = df['Cost'].where(df['Cost'] > 0)))
   Day Country  Type Product  Cost  new
0  Mon      US     1      a1     0  NaN
1  Mon      US     2      a1     5  5.0
2  Mon      US     3      a1     6  6.0
3  Mon      CA     1      a1     8  8.0
4  Mon      CA     2      a1     0  NaN
5  Mon      CA     3      a1     1  1.0


df['Average'] = (df.assign(new = df['Cost'].where(df['Cost'] > 0))
                   .groupby(['Country','Product'])['new']
                   .transform('mean'))
print (df)
   Day Country  Type Product  Cost  Average
0  Mon      US     1      a1     0      5.5
1  Mon      US     2      a1     5      5.5
2  Mon      US     3      a1     6      5.5
3  Mon      CA     1      a1     8      4.5
4  Mon      CA     2      a1     0      4.5
5  Mon      CA     3      a1     1      4.5
```

Or first filter, aggregate `mean` and assign back by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
s = df[df["Cost"] > 0].groupby(['Country','Product'])['Cost'].mean().rename('Average')
df = df.join(s, on=['Country','Product'])
print (df)
   Day Country  Type Product  Cost  Average
0  Mon      US     1      a1     0      5.5
1  Mon      US     2      a1     5      5.5
2  Mon      US     3      a1     6      5.5
3  Mon      CA     1      a1     8      4.5
4  Mon      CA     2      a1     0      4.5
5  Mon      CA     3      a1     1      4.5
```

Comment: I think in the first line you are missing `mean` somewhere.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - No, it is only for see new column how looks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`df[df["Cost"] > 0].groupby(['Country','Product'])["Cost"].mean()`

It filters out where cost is greater than zero, groups it and then takes the mean.

Comment: I don't think this would work if I had more numerical columns as you don't specify which columns mean to calculate.